# How to loop through array of objects to find if one exists

Tags: c++

When I created one account the deposit function in case 2 works but when I create two back to back and the code asks for the account number. Then it says it can't be found.

I created a function at the bottom to test to see if the account number is within the array but it doesn't seem to work.

I want help with matching the user inputted account number to see if it exists or not. Not sure how to do that. Fairly new to C++.

```
case 2:
            {
                cout << "Enter account number: ";
                cin >> accNum;

                int index = linSearch(accNum);

                if(index != -1)
                {
                Account * acc = accountArray[index];

                        cout << "Enter amount: ";
                        cin >> amount;

                        if(acc->deposit(amount) == 0)
                        {
                            cout << "New balance is " << acc->getBalance() << endl;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout << "Deposit failed" << endl;
                            break;
                        }
                }


                    if(index == -1)
                    {
                        cout << "No account found" << endl;
                        break;
                    }

                break;
            }
```

```
int linSearch(int & val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_NUM_ACCOUNTS; i++)
    {
        if  (accountArray[i]->getAccountNumber() == val)
            return i ;
    }
    return -1 ;
}
```

The code is supposed to ask for more than one account then deposit an amount into one of those accounts specified by the user by the account number

Comment: Bits and pieces of code is not useful in diagnosing problems. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps `accountArray` isn't initialized to the expected values? Try debugging the loop in `linSearch` or logging some diagnostics.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're posting the part with the error. Show the code where you add accounts to the accountArray[]

Comment: Probable Off-by-one bug. Assuming `accountArray` is of size `MAX_NUM_ACCOUNTS`,  in `for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_NUM_ACCOUNTS; i++)` the valid values of `i` are 0 through `MAX_NUM_ACCOUNTS` - 1 but `i <= MAX_NUM_ACCOUNTS;` allows 0 through `MAX_NUM_ACCOUNTS`.